# Customized View + Update Form using ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET MVC5 and already familiar with adding a scaffold item using MVC5 Controller with views using the Entity Framework.

Is there a way I can customize the web pages like this:
[image]

where I can split the existing records (first tab has 5, second has 4, and so on...) from the database on different tabs and update the values once.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a master view that gets partial view data via AJAX. Each partial view could have its own model. That way you can split the model logically into many views.
Once the values are changed you can post changes via JavaScript. You can use KnockoutJS to track changes to the model on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery UI Tabs to display the tabs. cut and paste the razor markup generated by the visual studio  to the respective tabs